# Python cannot kill a process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following python code:

```
main(): 
  t1 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(q,))

  t2 = Thread(target=server, args=(q,))
  t1.start()
  t2.start()

def server(q):
  while(1):

    # Produce some data
    data = s.recv(1000)
    q.put(data)
def consumer(in_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get()

        if(data.__len__() >0):
            pieces = data.split("\t")

            if 'L' in pieces[0]:
                l = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun1())
                l.start()
                n.terminate()
                n.join()

            elif 'N' in pieces[0]:
                n = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun2())
                n.start()
                l.terminate()
                l.join()
def func1():
while(1):
   //Do something


def func2():
while(1):
   //Do something code here
```

I want to kill or stop the process "l" when "n" is running and vice versa. I I tried `.terminate()` but I could not kill the process.

Is multiprocessing right way to do it? Could anyone tell me please what am I missing ? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your example is almost right, but is missing few things needed to help you. Good luck.

Comment: In your code : s is never defined, q is never defined, n is not defined in the "if L" block, l is not defined in the "If N" block.  Have a working example so we can reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem depends on the stuff that your processes `l` and `n` are doing (=> your functions `func1` and `func2`.

In your example you have a `while`function in each, so that can be used to control your process. In your case you can abuse the `multiprocessing.event`. It is designed to pause processes, not terminate them. But it should work as required.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def consumer(in_q):
    #create events for communication with processes, initialized as 'False'
    event_n = mp.event()
    event_l = mp.event()
    while True:
        data = in_q.get()

        if(data.__len__() >0):
            pieces = data.split("\t")

            if 'L' in pieces[0]:
                l = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=event_l)
                l.start()
                event_n.set() #set True and signal process n to stop
                n.join()

            elif 'N' in pieces[0]:
                n = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=event_n)
                n.start()
                event_l.set() #set True and signal process l to stop
                l.join()

def func1(event_l):
    while(!event_l): #do as long event_l == False
       //Do something
    event_l.clear() #set false
    return


def func2(event_n):
    while(!event_n): #do as long event_n == False
       //Do something code here
    event_n.clear() #set false
    return
```

However, your mixing of threads and processes is questionable. Your `server` and your `consumer`are in the same process, while your `func1` and `func2` are in separate processes. Is that your intention?

Comment: Thanks for your response.No, that was not intentional. I initially tried with different process and when that did not work I tried on the same process. Could you elaborate on the multiprocessing.event since I am a beginner .

Comment: The event-object (same for threads and processes) is a very simple way to sync and control process. see here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: By flagging the event `True` (calling `event.set()`) the main-thread can control on or more worker-threads. These workers have the `event.wait()` -method implemented that blocks the thread until the event becomes `True`. In this way you can sync, pause and resume threads in a very easy way. It is available in threads and processes. Here are some examples: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#signaling-between-processes